Adding a contents line to a "non-current" chapter
Potentially a very stupid question, but please humor me if you can. Suppose I have the following:
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The first chapter}
\section{The first section of ch1}
\section{The third section of ch1}

\chapter{The second chapter}
I'm writing here now!

\end{document}

Here's the question: is it at all possible to add something like
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{The second section of ch1}

where I wrote I'm writing here now! with an optional argument pointing to Chapter 1so that the table of contents prints as follows?
1 - The first chapter
        The first section of ch1
        The second section of ch1
        The third section of ch1
2 - The second chapter
        etc.


Care to provide details on why? Seems like you can just write \section{The second section of ch1} in the right place and move on. :-|

Broadly speaking, there are three ways to do it:

You implement your own TOC system from scratch and give it the characteristics you want it to have. (For example, I have had to do it to create thematic and alphabetical indexes.).
You implement a macro that, before rendering the index, opens the .toc file and orders things according to a certain parameter.


Could you tell me more (or point me in the right direction) about how you implemented thematic and alphabetical indexes?

Sure. I was helping a religious friend with a songbook of about 500 songs. Each song was entered into an environment receiving the name as a mandatory parameter. Internally, it saved the names of the songs, the song number and the page number as a triple and placed it inside a seq.
Since the indices were shown at the end, it was not necessary to export anything. Only, at the end of the document, with \seq_sort:Nn I sorted it and then showed the data as I wanted. See: https://paste.pics/RHC44

Thank you! That was helpful
